# Show the product price in installments using a dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add a dropdown menu where the visitor can choose between 12 months, and based on that choice, the price per month is shown in installments.

Lets say i have a product with price *120 usd*. A banner will inform the customer:

> "*you can purchase the item in installemets, select the the number*"

The customer will select for example 3 months and in the banner below the dropdown the result will be *40 usd /month*

Currently my code only works for 12 months.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'show_installments', 20 );
function show_installments() {
    global $product; 
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    $a   = $product->get_price();
    $b   = 12;
    $min = 25;
    $c   = round( $a / $b, 2);

   if ($a > $min)  {
       echo '<p class="p2_installments_12months">Purchase with'.$c.'€ per month for 12 months </p>';
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code, note that `jQuery` is also needed for the interaction between the dropdown and the editing of the text

```php
function show_installments() {
    global $product; 

    // Get product id   
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    // Get price
    $price = $product->get_price();

    // Set min price
    $min_price = 25;

    if ( $price > $min_price ) {

        echo '<div class="my_select_box">';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'month_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'label'         => __('You can purchase the item in installemets, select the the number'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Select...',
                '1'  => '1 month',
                '2'  => '2 months',
                '3'  => '3 months',
                '4'  => '4 months',
                '5'  => '5 months',
                '6'  => '6 months',
                '7'  => '7 months',
                '8'  => '8 months',
                '9'  => '9 months',
                '10'  => '10 months',
                '11'  => '11 months',
                '12'  => '12 months',
            )
        ), '' );

        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="p2_installments_12months"></div>';

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var product_price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>;

            $( '[name=month_options]' ).change(function() {
                var dropdown_val = this.value;

                if ( dropdown_val >= 1 ) {
                    var price_per_month = ( product_price / dropdown_val ).toFixed(2);

                    $( '.p2_installments_12months' ).html( '<p class="p2_installments_12months">Purchase with ' + price_per_month + ' € per month for 12 months </p>' );
                } else {
                    $( '.p2_installments_12months' ).html( '<p class="p2_installments_12months"></p>' );
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'show_installments', 20 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to add it as a code in widget using " php widget" plugin but it does not seem to operate. In functions.php works perfect! But it appears in under add to cart button

Comment: thank you for the clarification, is it possible to show this code in sidebar widget?